# R shiny - How to change family font for base graphics using par()?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, font-family, par

I am using the `eegcap2d` function in the `library(eegkit)`. This function plots a figure by using the base graphics. I want to change the family font, which can be easily done in R by setting `par(family = 'Times New Roman')` for instance. However, this does not seem to work with shiny.

I already tried to change the family font for the entire R Shiny App by setting

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$style( * {font-family: Times New Roman; }')
  ## More code here
)
```

But this does not seem to work on any `renderPlot` or `renderPlotly`.

Then I tried, to set it directly in the `renderPlot` function. This is a simple example of what I did:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("newplot", "New plot")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      input$newplot
      # Add a little noise to the cars data
      cars2 <- cars + rnorm(nrow(cars))
      par(family = 'Times New Roman', font = 3)
      plot(cars2)
      title('My Title')
    })
  }
)
```

No matter what values I put in the `par` the plot doesn't change.
What settings should I use?

Comment: your example code works for me. it could be that the other package plot methods you are using are setting the family explicitly, so your settings are ignored

Comment: For me, even this simple example does not work. There is no difference on the plot no matter what family font I choose. Are you on Windows? Could it be because I'm on Linux?

Comment: i tried on mac and linux (arch) and both worked. windows did not, I had to do something like `windowsFonts(TNR = 'Times New Roman'); plot(..., family = 'TNR')` which worked. have you tried `family = 'serif'` instead? I don't notice any difference other than the width of `0`s is a tiny bit different

Comment: If you write ```dev.new(); 
plot(cars2);
text(x = 5, y = 100, labels = "My Title", cex = 2, family = 'Roboto' );
text(x = 5, y = 80, labels = "My Title", cex = 2, family = 'serif' );
text(x = 5, y = 60, labels = "My Title", cex = 2, family = 'Times New Roman' )``` you can easily see the difference between the family fonts. However if you try to integrate the ```text``` inside the shiny app, there is no more difference.

Comment: [this](https://i.imgur.com/76VVuRT.png) is what I get on arch (not using shiny). [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svglite/vignettes/fonts.html) claims that serif and times are mapped on most systems

Comment: Did you try with shiny? ```output$plot <- renderPlot({
      cars2 <- cars + rnorm(nrow(cars));
      plot(cars2); text(x = 5, y = 100, labels = "My Title", cex = 2, family = 'Roboto' ); text(x = 5, y = 80, labels = "My Title", cex = 2, family = 'serif' ); text(x = 5, y = 60, labels = "My Title", cex = 2, family = 'Times New Roman' )
          })```  If so, do you get the same result?